# Couchbase script with combination of cbq and cbimport commands is not working

Tags: bash, couchbase, sql++

I am trying to write a script file which will export some data using [cbq][1] commands and then import those data into target cluster via [cbimport][2] commands. I want to enhance the script in such a way that it can export huge data and import on another cluster.
However in my local machine, it is failing. Actually script is getting **stuck** in the **SELECT command of the cbq** command.

Can someone suggest me how to do it. Below is the test script which I am using:

```bash
echo "Hello World"
cbq -u Administrator -p Administrator -e "http://localhost:8093";
\REDIRECT temp.txt;
SELECT * FROM `sample.data` where id="106" --output="temp.txt";
\REDIRECT OFF;
cbimport json -c http://{target-cluster}:8091 -u Administrator -p Administrator  -b sample.data -d file://C:\Users\myusername\Desktop\temp.txt -f list -g %docId%;
\EXIT;
```

Below is the response of above script:

```bash
$ ./test.sh
Hello World
 Connected to : http://localhost:8093/. Type Ctrl-D or \QUIT to exit.

 Path to history file for the shell : C:\Users\myuser\.cbq_history
```

And getting stuck here for very long time.

Comment: does the query work okay otherwise? is the bucket actually called "sample.data", or is that meant to be a collection?

Comment: https://forums.couchbase.com/t/cbimport-not-working-as-expected/32292

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifically for this script of yours, you have a semi-colon terminating the cbq invocation after the URL, so it is simply in interactive mode.

You would want to try:

```
echo "Hello World"

cbq -u Administrator -p Administrator -e "http://localhost:8093"  --output="temp.txt" -s "SELECT * FROM `sample.data` where id='106'"
# add processing to convert from redirected output to cbimport format
cbimport json -c http://{target-cluster}:8091 -u Administrator -p Administrator  -b sample.data -d file://C:\Users\myusername\Desktop\temp.txt -f list -g %docId%
```

as the 3 commands in your script.  (Note no use of double quotes in the statement, since the chosen quotes for the shell are double quotes. You could invert this choice too.)

Comment: Thanks for answer. Using the same approach I was able to produce the desire result. Below are the command I used. 

```cbq -u Administrator -p ${password} -q -e “ http://localhost:8093” --script=“select * FROM com.test.default` where id==”“106"”;" | jq -c ‘.results[0].“com.test.result”’ > ${file} ` 
cbimport json -c http://{target-cluster}:8091 -u Administrator -p ${password} -b com.test.result -d file://${file} -f lines -g %docId%```